# Change WooCommerce Product Permalink Structure

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks, htaccess, production

According to my suppliers they want the local site and the international site to have the same product URL's just different domain. However my site is built on WooCommerce and there's is a custom PHP integration.

I have been haggling for days to try and get this to work by htaccess (I'm no Pro) and via a custom Permalinks plug-in without any luck.

I'm not sure if it is possible but I need the URL structure to be like this:

**From:**

```
https://example.com/artnr/10616/
```

**To:**

```
https://example.com/?artnr=10616
```

Comment: The `/?artnr=10616` URL just _looks like_ a non-pretty-permalink URL? Does that URL "work" if you request it?